# "AuthorizationManager check failed" in PowerShell, fixed after restarting WMI

Tags: windows, windows-8, windows-10, powershell

About once a day, PowerShell scripts will stop working on my computer with an error that looks like this.

```
AuthorizationManager check failed.
At line:1 char:3
+ . .\matt.ps1
+   ~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : SecurityError: (:) [], PSSecurityException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccess
```

I'm not changing my execution policy ("Remote-Signed").  The Windows Management Instrumentation service is running.  Restarting WMI always fixes the problem.  I looked at the event logs, I see some DCOM errors, maybe they are related?

```
The server {784E29F4-5EBE-4279-9948-1E8FE941646D} did not register with DCOM within the required timeout.
The application-specific permission settings do not grant Local Activation permission for the COM Server application with CLSID 
{D63B10C5-BB46-4990-A94F-E40B9D520160}
 and APPID 
{9CA88EE3-ACB7-47C8-AFC4-AB702511C276}
 to the user NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM SID (S-1-5-18) from address LocalHost (Using LRPC) running in the application container Unavailable SID (Unavailable). This security permission can be modified using the Component Services administrative tool.
```

This has been going on for months, even after an upgrade from Windows 8 to Windows 10. I'd love a solution.

Comment: which host are you using to create your script? which encoding do the scripts have which cause the problem? what happens when you run your script with the `-noprofile` parameter so your PS Profile won't be loaded - does the error still occur?

Comment: If you spend a day running only one simplistic script and no others (eg `Write-Output 'foo'`?), does the error still occur? You should eliminate some fault within your routine scripts.